# NodeJS and MongoDB "Cannot POST /"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, mongoose

Been using mongoDB with the mongoose ODM and I can't seem to figure it out. I've been following a tutorial online, but when I test out my code, it gets redirected to an empty page that says "Cannot POST /"

Here is my code:

server.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


var PORT = 3332;

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/gamedata", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});


var gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nickname: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", gameSchema);


app.post("/addname", (req, res) =>{

    var playerNickname = new User(req.body);
    playerNickname.save()
    .then(item => {

        console.log("nickname created")
        res.send("item saved to database");


    })
    .catch(err => {

        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
        console.log("error baby!");

    });
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("server is up and running using port " + PORT)
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
<h1 class="center-align">Create Nickname</h1>
    <form method="post" name="/addname">
        <input id="pickName" type='text' name='pickName' placeholder='Nickname' required>
        <input id='ready' value=" Ready >" type='submit'>
    </form>

</body>
<script>
</script>

</html>
```

What seems to fix it is when i change

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
```

to the following code:

```
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

But in my specific case i cannot do this.

Does anyone know of a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your **index.html**

Insteady of use:

```
 <form method="post" name="/addname">
```

you should use:

```
<form method="post" action="/addname">
```

This should solve your problem.

---

The Action Attribute

The action attribute defines the action to be performed when the form is submitted.

Usually, the form data is sent to a page on the server when the user clicks on the submit button.

In the example above, the form data is sent to a page on the server called "/addname". This page contains a script that handles the form data:

If the **action** attribute is omitted, the action is set to the current page.

The attribute "name" is used in input fields, not in the  tag.
I just found some information here.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp